# Can I send email verification every time the user login instead of using password in firebase (Flutter)?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

For some reason, I don't want the users to register and login with password in my Flutter application using Firebase, Is there any way to let the user enter his email only, then I send email verification to his email every time he login. Also I don't want to register using phone number.

Comment: If a person suddenly loses his email, like it was a corporate email and he got fired, how will you authenticate the user when the only thing you have is a now-dead email?  You need to think this through.

Comment: This is an example I found on the website for your reference, [Login with Email](https://itnext.io/flutter-passwordless-login-with-firebase-8cb085c4fb67)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is known as the [email link provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth) in Firebase, which sends an email message with a link to sign-in.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, you can create and have a user with no password.

Using provider:

```js
export function signInUsingProvider(providerDomain: string) {
    return signInWithPopup(getAuth(), new OAuthProvider(providerDomain))
}

signInUsingProvider('google.com')
```

You ask the browser to give you some information about user logged in google.com account and browser gives you some information about this user, so you can authenticate him. Email will be verified automatically.

Sign in with email link:

```js
const actionCodeSettings = {
  // URL you want to redirect back to. The domain (www.example.com) for this
  // URL must be in the authorized domains list in the Firebase Console.
  url: 'https://www.example.com/finishSignUp?cartId=1234',
  // This must be true.
  handleCodeInApp: true,
  iOS: {
    bundleId: 'com.example.ios'
  },
  android: {
    packageName: 'com.example.android',
    installApp: true,
    minimumVersion: '12'
  },
  dynamicLinkDomain: 'example.page.link'
};

sendSignInLinkToEmail(getAuth(), email, actionCodeSettings)
```

Basically, it sends an email with a link with will authenticate you. For more details, visit [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth).

**Remember that if you have not set password, you cannot for example delete an account!**